# Rename columns in 1 table to row values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Ok, so I have 2 tables in all:

- `Table 1` has these 3 columns which are not meaningful as they are just a `varchar` value:

  ```
  Q19243  Q19244  Q19245
  ```
- `Table 2` has 2 columns `ColumnName` and `TextValue`.

`ColumnName` holds the values of the name of the 3 columns in `Table 1` (`Q19243` etc) and also has a corresponding column called `TextValue` which holds a friendly description of what `Q19243` actually means.

So there are 3 records in `Table 2`, 1 for each column in `Table 1`.

I would like to rename these 3 columns in `Table 1` to equal whatever is in the `TextValue` column in `Table 2`. I would like to do this dynamically rather than a simple `UPDATE` statement to rename the columns. Sorry I did not attach screen shots but I do not see an attach button to do so...

If you run this code to create an example of the 2 tables then you should probably have a better idea of what I'm referring to.

```
create table #Table1 (Q19243 varchar(10),Q19244 varchar(10),Q19245 varchar(10))

Create table #Table2 (ColumnName varchar(10),TextValue varchar(50))

Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19243','Provider Name'
Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19244','The Provider You Usually See'
Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19245','How Long Going to Provider'

select * from #Table1
select * from #Table2

drop table #Table1
drop table #Table2
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Constantly renaming columns will make it impossible to have queries against the table. Do you just nee to rename the fields for the sake of output? There might be a better way to accomplish the end goal but it is hard to tell without knowing what that end goal is.

Comment: I never want to query against this table, this is strictly for output purposes.  I want to rename each column in Table 1 to what is in the 'TextValue' field in Table 2.  So for the first field in Table1, it is named 'Q19243'.  There is a corresponding record in Table2 for 'Q19243', if you look in the first field (ColumnName) in Table2 you see it's value is 'Q19243' and it's TextValue (Column2 in Table 2) is 'Provider Name'.  I want to rename column 'Q19243' in Table1 to be called 'Provider Name'.  See how the field name in Table1 ties to the 'ColumnName' in Table2??

Comment: Why have the table at all?  Why not just have a query's resultset with the column name you want?

Comment: It's not as easy as that, at least for me.  We have a large process that pretty much returns the data with all the fields named 'Q19243' etc.  Too large for me to get into and start trying to modify.  I was just trying to add a piece at the end that renames the columns dynamically to something more meanable than 'Q19243'.  Table2 will always hold the column names that are in Table1 so with this I thought it would be relatively easy enough to rename the columns in Table1 based on the values in Table2.  I'm not exactly sure how to do this but I thought someone else might know of a way...

Comment: Hi, see this: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0bad/1
if you table exists maybe usefull, only change the table's name

Answer (score 2):

Since the purpose of the column rename is for output purposes only, you can use a query against Table2 to create Dynamic SQL specific to Table1 that aliases the column names on the SELECT.

(the following example uses the sample code in the original question and only differs by what is between the `--==============` lines)

```
create table #Table1 (Q19243 varchar(10),Q19244 varchar(10),Q19245 varchar(10))

Create table #Table2 (ColumnName nvarchar(10),TextValue nvarchar(50))

Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19243','Provider Name'
Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19244','The Provider You Usually See'
Insert into #Table2 select 'Q19245','How Long Going to Provider'

select * from #Table1
select * from #Table2

--=========================================
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + N',', N'SELECT')
               + N' t1.'
               + t2.ColumnName
               + N' AS ['
               + t2.TextValue
               + N']'
FROM #Table2 t2

SET @SQL = @SQL + N' FROM #Table1 t1'

SELECT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)
--=========================================

drop table #Table1
drop table #Table2
```

The value of `@SQL` after the `SELECT @SQL=` query is:

> SELECT t1.Q19243 AS [Provider Name], t1.Q19244 AS [The Provider You
>   Usually See], t1.Q19245 AS [How Long Going to Provider] FROM #Table1
>   t1

Note: you need the square-brackets around the field name alias (value from Table2.TextValue) as there are spaces in the string.

Comment: Sweet!  This looks exactly like what I need!!  It seems to be working initially so I will continue to play with this and see if I can implement it in my process.  Thanks so much for the help guys, particularly you srutzky!!!!!

Comment: @user3403092: no problem. Usually the context of the question is just as important as the question itself :).

Comment: @user3403092: also, if this does work, please remember to mark this as the accepted answer. And make sure you have the most recent code from the answer as I edited a few times to reduce the SELECT to its simplest form.