# Oracle PL/SQL set column names using other table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm struggling with naming columns in one table, using a reference table containing these names. I'm sure it should be possible, but I can't seem to find the right solution or think of the correct logic to achieve it...

Situation: I got 2 tables, one with data, columns having descriptive names, and one with a translation of these column names to meaningful names (reference table, or 'codebook').

I'm looking for a way to return the data of the first table, with the names of the columns given in the second column of the second table.

Tables look like:

```
dataTable:
q1,q2,q3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

and

```
translationTable:
descName, meanName
q1, meaning1
q2, meaning2
q3, meaning3
```

Result should be:

```
meaning1,meaning2,meaning3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I didn't search hard enough, excuses! Both the problem and answer are explained here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309099/rename-columns-in-1-table-to-row-values-in-another-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly do it, because you need a query whose columns are variable, based on some value.
Slightly different, what you can do is build a dynamic SQL to have your query created by Oracle:

SETUP:

```
SQL> create table dataTable(q1,q2,q3) as
  2  select 1,2,3 from dual union all
  3  select 4,5,6 from dual
  4  ;

Table created.

SQL> create table translationTable(descName, meanName) as
  2  select 'q1', 'meaning1' from dual union all
  3  select 'q2', 'meaning2' from dual union all
  4  select 'q3', 'meaning3' from dual ;

Table created.
```

This will create and print your query:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vSQL varchar2(1000);
  3  begin
  4      select listagg (column_name || ' AS "' || meanName || '"', ', ') within group (order by column_name)
  5      into vSQL
  6      from user_tab_columns col
  7        inner join translationTable    tr
  8          on (upper(tr.descName) = col.column_name)
  9      where table_name = upper('dataTable');
 10      --
 11      vSQL := 'select ' || vSQL || ' from dataTable';
 12      dbms_output.put_line(vSQL);
 13  end;
 14  /
select Q1 AS "meaning1", Q2 AS "meaning2", Q3 AS "meaning3" from dataTable

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you copy the statement and run it:

```
SQL> select Q1 AS "meaning1", Q2 AS "meaning2", Q3 AS "meaning3" from dataTable;

  meaning1   meaning2   meaning3
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2          3
         4          5          6

SQL>
```

This way you have your query, but you can not fetch it, because it still has variable columns.

You can easily edit this code to make it build a query that returns strings, composed by concatenating the felds; this way you will always have a single field, but it's different from what you asked:

```
SQL> select 'meaning1, meaning2, meaning3' from dual
  2  union all
  3  select Q1 || ',' || Q2 || ',' ||  Q3 from dataTable;

'MEANING1,MEANING2,MEANING3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
meaning1, meaning2, meaning3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```